# Quick question on validity of arguments across propositional and predicate logic

Tags: logic

Could someone clarify a quick question regarding the following please?

From the text:

> Assume Γ ⊭ ϕ. Then there is an L2-structure A such that all members of
>   Γ are true in A and ϕ is false in A. Derive an L1-structure A′ from A
>   by omitting the domain and the interpretations of constants and n-ary
>   predicate letters for n ≥ 1. Since the satisfaction clauses of
>   sentence letters and the propositional connectives of L2 are the same
>   in L1 and L2, all members of Γ are true in A′ and ϕ is false in A′

I understand that arguments that are invalid in L1 are also invalid in L2 but why is the opposite true ?

Starting with a logically invalid L2-Argument with quantified sentences in the premisses say, how would removing interpretations of constants/n-ary predicate letters from the L2-structure account for the fact that L1 cannot deal with quantifiers?

Thanks!

Comment: What are L1 and L2?

Comment: languages of propositional and predicate logic respectively. :)

Comment: What is the context ? And the text ?

Comment: Example of invalis FOl : **∃xPx⊭∀xPx**. Domain = { 1,2 } and Int of **P** : "x is Even".

Comment: The issue is : how to manufacture an L1-structure **A′** form **A** above ? **A'** must be a truth valuation **v** such that **v(∃xPx)=T** and **v(∀xPx)=F**. And this is indeed possible...

Comment: ok then..... :-)

Answer (score -1):

The question is

> Starting with a logically invalid L2-Argument with quantified sentences in the premisses say, how would removing interpretations of constants/n-ary predicate letters from the L2-structure account for the fact that L1 cannot deal with quantifiers?

L1 means propositional logic. L2 means predicate logic.  A first order language contains logical symbols which when combined into well-formed formulas can be assigned a truth value. It also contains non-logical symbols which require an interpretation prior to assigning a truth value to a formula.

A structure is a way to specify an interpretation. Here is [Wikipedia's description](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic#First-order_structures) of structure and interpretation:

> The most common way of specifying an interpretation (especially in mathematics) is to specify a structure (also called a model; see below). The structure consists of a nonempty set D that forms the domain of discourse and an interpretation I of the non-logical terms of the signature.

One can look at the formulas resulting from the interpretation as propositional forumlas that have been assigned a truth value. As an example, this [tree proof generator](https://www.umsu.de/logik/trees/) will either generate a tree or provide a countermodel. Consider the following invalid argument:

[image]

This is a structure. The domain has only one element 0. P is an empty predicate since no value of the domain makes it true. Therefore, it is false. Q does have a value from the domain, 0, that makes it true. So Q, with the element 0, is true. The disjunction has the value true. The consequent is the predicate P again, but there is no value from the domain that makes P true. So the consequent is false.

If we ignored the domain and interpretation we could construct the following propositional logic result from this result:

[image]

Again we have P is false while Q is true giving a similar result. We can ignore the domain in this countermodel. This might be what the text is asking you to do when it says:

> Derive an L1-structure A′ from A by omitting the domain and the interpretations of constants and n-ary predicate letters for n ≥ 1.

However, the textbook may be asking for a detailed proof not just an example and a suggestion why it should be true in general. If that is the case, then one should use the precise way the textbook defines *language*, *L1 structure* and *L2 structure*, and any already proven propositions relating these structures to provide a proof of the result. Also imitate the proofs given for those earlier propositions.

---

Wikipedia contributors. (2019, June 27). First-order logic. In Wikipedia, The Free Encyclopedia. Retrieved 15:57, July 5, 2019, from https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=First-order_logic&oldid=903705274

Tree Proof Generator. Retrieved on July 5, 2019 from https://www.umsu.de/logik/trees/